# collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a dynamic collectionView in TableView and there are an bug when I add `invalidateLayout` (picture is below)
but if I delete `invalidateLayout` the first four cells are hidden and the layout is not displayed correctly, the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DRXLXQgXhrc__ImDjZMDoqrEJdCKFIKs/view?usp=sharing)

**please help I searched the whole stack but nothing helped thanks**

if you need test [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klq1Y6caxQBR5l2ySajE-XDb6mRKGgW-/view?usp=sharing)

MainViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setting()
    }

  func setting(){

   getData()

   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.delegate = self

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension 
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension    

  }

         //load data
   func pagination(_ completion: (()->())?){

      SmartNetworkSevrice.getGoods(with: url) { [unowned self] (data) in
         guard data.modals.count > 0 else {
             self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
             return
         }

         self.goods.append(contentsOf: data.modals)
         self.offSet += data.modals.count
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
             self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil
             if self.goods.count == data.modals.count || self.isRefresh {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
             } else {
                if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TVCellGoods {
                    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        cell.insertGoods(data.modals)
                        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                        cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                     }

                }
             }
            completion?()
         }
     }

     // define bottom of tableView
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        guard scrollView == self.tableView else {  return }
        if (!isMoreDataLoading) {

            // Вычислить позицию длины экрана до нижней части результатов
            let scrollViewContentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
            let scrollOffsetThreshold = scrollViewContentHeight - scrollView.bounds.size.height
            if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollOffsetThreshold && scrollView.isDragging) {
                isMoreDataLoading = true
                self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false;
                self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true;
                pagination(nil)
            }
        }

       }

    }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "goods", for: indexPath) as? TVCellGoods else { return UITableViewCell() }
              guard bestGoods.count != 0, goods.count != 0 else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.configure(bestGoods, goods, categories)
            // автообновление высоты
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
            return cell 
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, CallDelegate {

    func callMethod() {}

    func callMethod(push vc:UIViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

}
```

TableViewCell with collectionView

```
class TVCellGoods: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight:NSLayoutConstraint!

    weak var delegate:CallDelegate?
    var bestGoods = [Goods]() // лучшие товары
    var goods = [Goods]() // все товары
    var categories = [Menu]()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.tag = 2
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configure(_ best:[Goods],_ goods:[Goods], _ category:[Menu]) {

        self.bestGoods = best
        self.goods = goods
        self.categories = category
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    func insertGoods(_ data:[Goods]) {

        self.goods.append(contentsOf: data)
        let count = self.bestGoods.count + self.categories.count  + self.goods.count
        let indexPaths = ((count - data.count) ..< count)
            .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

and CollectionViewCell

```
class CVCellGoods: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var delivery: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var premium: UIImageView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        delivery.image = nil
        premium.image = nil
        title.text = nil
        price.text = nil
        imageView.image = nil
        imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 215/255, green: 215/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1)

        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.5)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    }

}
```

**Edit**

if I use

```
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
        })
```

with `invalidateLayout` then I get an empty space at the bottom of the screen 
[image: screen]
but if I delete `invalidateLayout` I get wrong Layout [image: Layout]

**if you don’t have it like mine, then discard the project with your improvements**

**SECOND Edit**

I noticed that there is an indentation on the iPhone 11 Pro and everything is fine on the iPhone 11 Pro Max

[image: iPhone 11 Pro IOS 13.3]

[image: iPhone 11 Pro Max IOS 13.3]

Comment: Please check my updated answer and give it a try. It should solve your layout problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I verified this works on the simulators for iPhone SE, 11, and 11 Max with no dead space at the end of the collection view.

> My simulator is set to dark mode to show that the bottom of the collection view is just enough for the loading icon.

[image]

I had to make a few changes for this to properly size. First, I changed your `insertGoods` function in `TVCellGoods` class to reload only the newly added items after inserting and it no longer has missing items at the top of the list:

```
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
    })
```

A big problem was setting the estimated row height for your tableView cells. I've removed the `estimatedHeightForRowAt` override and replaced your `heightForRowAt` with this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return (tableView.frame.width / 2.5) + 20
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return 70
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TVCellGoods else { return UITableView.automaticDimension }
//            print(cell.collectionViewHeight.constant)
            return cell.collectionViewHeight.constant
        }
    }
```

I also had to add `layoutIfNeeded` to your cellForRow at in your `ViewController UITableViewDataSource` extension:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
self.tableView.endUpdates()
cell.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Lastly, I had to update your `layoutSubviews` to assign the correct height after invalidating the layout in `TVCellGoods`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

> Here is the updated source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ldr4Ml2prZKmr1C4i1s5Sg7LvvxL7-jO

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213823/discussion-on-answer-by-elliott-io-collectionview-collectionviewlayout-invalidat).